# ESP32 HTTPS POST JSON to AWS

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, esp32

I'm trying to post some data to AWS over HTTPS post but seems not to reach there.

Setting host to server address and path to /prod
No authentication is required yet on the method.
When I connect it just gets frozen and no response,
despite saying it's connected.

Also tried not to use path and set the full path to the host

Not really sure why it's happening, these are 2 ways I tried:

```
    void postToAmazonSecure(String jsonToSend){
  WiFiClientSecure client;
  
  Serial.print("connecting to : '");
  Serial.print(emonDataAPI);
  Serial.println("'");
  Serial.println(emonDataAPI.c_str());
  client.connect(emonDataAPI.c_str(), 443);
  
  Serial.print("requesting URL: '");
  Serial.print(emonDataAPI);
  Serial.println("'");
  String requestString = String("POST ") + emonDataAPIPath + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
    "Host: " + emonDataAPI + "\r\n" +
    "Connection: close\r\n" +
    "Content-Type: application/json" +
    //"Authorization: Bearer " + authorization_code + "\r\n" +
    "Content-Length: " + jsonToSend.length() + "\r\n" +
    "\r\n" +
    jsonToSend + "\r\n";
    Serial.println(requestString);
  client.print(requestString);
  
  Serial.println("request sent");
  unsigned long timeout = millis();
  while (client.available() == 0) {
    if (millis() - timeout > 5000) {
      Serial.println(">>> Client Timeout !");
      client.stop();
      return;
    }
}
}

void postSecure(String jsonToSend){
 WiFiClientSecure client;

 Serial.print("connect: "); Serial.println(emonDataAPI);
 while ( ! client.connect(emonDataAPI.c_str(), 443)) {
    Serial.print(".");
 }
 Serial.println("Connected");
 String msg = "POST " + emonDataAPIPath + " HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                "Host: " + emonDataAPI + "\r\n"
                "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
                "Content-Length: " + jsonToSend.length() + "\r\n"
                "\r\n" + jsonToSend;
                
 client.print(msg);
 Serial.print(msg);
 
 Serial.print("\n*** Request sent, receiving response...");
 while (!!!client.available()) {
    delay(50);
 Serial.print(".");
  }
  
Serial.println();
Serial.println("Got response");  
  while(client.available()){
  Serial.write(client.read());
  }
Serial.println(); Serial.println("closing connection");
  client.stop();
}
```

Comment: Any reason in particular you're doing all the rest stuff manually? For a Post request using HTTPClient would save you some work. Example here: https://www.teachmemicro.com/esp32-restful-api/

Comment: Seriously, what @AlexMantaut said. People screw up HTTP so often when they do it manually. Especially when they're doing HTTPS. Just use the library that already gets it right. Also - does it work when you use a program like `curl`?

Comment: Also tryed this but always getting -1 response code.
When i call from postman it works whit the body logged in serial monitor.

```

void postToAmazon(String jsonToSend){
if(WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED){
      WiFiClientSecure client;
      HTTPClient http;
      http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      // Your Domain name with URL path or IP address with path
      http.begin(client, emonDataAPI);
      http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      int httpResponseCode = http.POST(jsonToSend);
       http.end();
    }
    }
```

Comment: That's good debugging :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the `\r\n` at the end of the `Content-Type` line. It should be:

```
"Content-Type: application/json\r\n" +
```

You're also not providing `WiFiClientSecure` with a fingerprint or certificate so that it can verify the server you're connecting to. This is also going to stop your code from working. You should provide the root certificate for the certificate chain securing the endpoint you're trying to connect to:

```
const char* test_root_ca= \
     "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" \
...
     "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";


...

  client.setCACert(test_root_ca);
  client.connect(emonDataAPI.c_str(), 443);
```

You can find a more complete example in the [WiFiClientSecure library examples](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WiFiClientSecure/examples/WiFiClientSecure/WiFiClientSecure.ino).

You can also check out the [README for WiFiClientSecure](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/WiFiClientSecure) for more detailed information.

Without the root certificate `WiFiClientSecure` cannot verify the identity of the server you're connecting to. Windows, Linux and macOS systems all handle this automatically; the overhead to doing this is more than the ESP32's operating environment can handle.

You can tell `WiFiClientSecure` not to bother verifying the server, but by doing so you're also saying "I don't really care about security". You might do this for debugging but it's an extremely poor and dangerous practice to leave it in code that's actually being used.

```
  client.setInsecure();
  client.connect(emonDataAPI.c_str(), 443);
```

These kinds of mistakes are a big part of why you're almost always better off using a library like [`HTTPClient`](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/HTTPClient) than rolling your own HTTP(S) implementation.

Comment: Thanks will try that out, but the certificate was optional right?

Comment: If you want the connection to actually connect, you need to either provide the information it needs to verify the identity of the server or you need to tell it not to bother. I've updated the answer with a little more info.

Comment: Hi again, thank you for the help.
But in this specific case i did some more tests and i think it's the server blocking the connection, maybe not sure.
In the browser and in postman if i try to connect to the host(not the full api path) i get connection refused.
But i'm just having client timeouts in the code, even whit the insecure.
Marking as accepted answer but still not sure on what's going on.
Ended up going whit an old laptop acting as my server and deployed my api there :D made it "in house" literally :D

Comment: If you're getting Connection Refused then you probably have either the wrong AWS endpoint or you haven't set up AWS permissions correctly (which happens a lot).

Comment: to the host in the code i just get timeout, in postman if i do a simple get or post just to the host whit no path i get refused and if i browse just the host i get the same thing refused.

Comment: seams it's not a amazon issue or at least not just...
Reduced to this(local ip http) but still getting -1 response code. Any ideas? :D 
```
void postToEmon(String jsonToSend){
if(WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED){
     WiFiClient client;
      HTTPClient http;
    http.begin(client,emonDataAPI.c_str());
      http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      int httpResponseCode = http.POST(jsonToSend);
    
      http.end();
    }
}```

Comment: Never mind just missed the http:// in the url :D working, so, seams to be something whit aws, probably needs some kind of library like firebase