# How to solve error 400 when using esp32 to aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, esp32

new here.

I´m working on a project I'm trying to post some data to AWS over HTTPS post but seems not to work properly since i get a 400 message as a response. I have already tried from Postman and works fine my API.

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

const char* ssid = "";
const char* password = "";

//Domain name with URL path or IP address with path
const char* serverName = ""



unsigned long lastTime = 0;
unsigned long timerDelay = 5000;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("Connecting");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to WiFi network with IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  Serial.println("Timer set to 5 seconds (timerDelay variable), it will take 5 seconds before publishing the first reading.");
}

void loop() {
  //Send an HTTP POST request every 10 minutes
  if ((millis() - lastTime) > timerDelay) {
    //Check WiFi connection status
    if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
      WiFiClient client;
      HTTPClient http;

      // Your Domain name with URL path or IP address with path
      http.begin(client, serverName);

      http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      int httpResponseCode = http.POST("{\"INPUT\": \"hello world\"}");

      

      Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
      Serial.println(httpResponseCode);

      // Free resources
      http.end();
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("WiFi Disconnected");
    }
    lastTime = millis();
  }
}
```

Any syggestions on what could be the solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ESP32 HTTPS POST JSON to AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68568043/esp32-https-post-json-to-aws)

Comment: I think you can use `WiFiClientSecure` for https.

Answer (score -3):

For the content type you need to add the "\r\n" characters:

```
"Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
```

You might also need to pass the certificate information if it is required.
See this article for more details:

[esp32-https-post-json-to-aws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68568043/esp32-https-post-json-to-aws)

Comment: This is incorrect; you absolutely do not need to add "\r\n" when you use the `addHeader()` method. It does it for you. You only need that if you're doing your own implementation of HTTP.